# Moving a resource in maven with wildcard

Tags: maven, file, copy, wildcard

I was trying to move a file to an existing one with a variable (cache busted) part:
file.js should be copied over an existing file-0123456789abcdef.js (of which the last part 16 hex digits is variable)
The copy-rename-maven-plugin results in an extra file: file-*.js:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>move-file</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/unpacked/file.js</sourceFile>
        <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/unpacked/file-*.js</destinationFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would like to end up with one file: file-0123456789abcdef.js with the content of file.js.
A simple terminal command can easily do what I want but I would like to avoid using the ant plugin.
Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the exec-maven-plugin could do the trick in combination with a find -exec:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>move-configuration</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>find</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>${project.build.directory}/unpacked/>
      <argument>-name</argument>
      <argument>file-*.js</argument>
      <argument>-exec</argument>
      <argument>mv</argument>
      <argument>${project.build.directory}/unpacked/file.js</argument>
      <argument>{}</argument>
      <argument>;</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```